# xfire web-service client gets null response

Tags: java, web-services, xfire

I use xfire to develop a web-service client in my Spring 3.x project, here are my code below

```
WebServiceClient wClient = new WebServiceClient();
WebServiceSoap soap = wClient.getWebServiceSoap(Commons.VD_INFO_WSDL);

com.webservice.object.GetVDInfo input = new com.webservice.object.GetVDInfo();
input.setPASSWORD(Commons.VD_INFO_PASSWORD);
com.webservice.object.GetVDInfoResponse response = soap.getVDInfo(input);
System.out.println(response==null ? "response=null" : "response not null,");
```

When I run these on the server, I can see the wsdl was get on my Eclipse console, but the "response" object is null....
Here is the final part log below, Can anyone give me a hint or suggestion?
If there is not enough information, plz let me know....
thx so much...

```
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "   <wsdl:service name="ToServiceImplService">[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "[\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "      <wsdl:port binding="impl:ToServiceImplSoapBinding" name="ToServiceImpl">[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "[\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://xx.xx.10.77/TO_SERVICE/services/ToServiceImpl"/>[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "[\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "      </wsdl:port>[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "[\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "   </wsdl:service>[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "[\n]"
DEBUG: httpclient.wire.content - << "</wsdl:definitions>[\r][\n]"
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=http://61.60.10.77]
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.IdleConnectionHandler - Adding connection at: 1404713700948
DEBUG: org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase pre-dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.client.CorrelatorHandler in phase pre-dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client - Correlating context with ID 14047137002771-1400602077
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client - Found correlated context with ID 14047137002771-1400602077
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - adding handler org.codehaus.xfire.client.ClientReceiveHandler@37e80c87 to phase service
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.handler.LocateBindingHandler in phase dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.soap.handler.SoapBodyHandler in phase dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.soap.handler.SoapActionInHandler in phase dispatch
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase policy
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase user
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase pre-invoke
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.soap.handler.ValidateHeadersHandler in phase pre-invoke
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking phase service
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline - Invoking handler org.codehaus.xfire.client.ClientReceiveHandler in phase service
DEBUG: org.codehaus.xfire.client.XFireProxy - Result [null]
response=null
```